# How to import data into mysql

Tags: mysql

While I tried to load data into mysql, I encountered a problem. I have data like

123456     I am happy\nI am not happy

123457     I cannot.

The data may contain \n itself. So I cannot use \n as the delimiter. What can I do to preserve the \n in the sentence. By the way, I only have 2 columns.

Comment: How are you loading the data (CSV/SCRIPT/QUERYS)?

Comment: If you had this in CSV format there wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: It's a text file. Why would you say if it's CSV, then it would not be a problem?